# Pandas read_csv get rid of enclosing double quotes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Here is my example:

I first create dataframe and save it to file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[['a','b','s'], 23423]})
df.to_csv(r'C:\test.csv')
```

Then `df.col_1[0]` returns `['a','b','s']` a list

Later I read it from file:

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\test.csv', quoting = 3, quotechar = '"')
```

Now `df_1['col_1'][0]` returns `"['a'     's']"` a string.

I would like to get list back. I am experimenting with different `read_csv` settings, but so far no luck

Comment: CSVs are not meant to save complex data structures, only tabular numerical/text data.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you, I would normally use pickle, but ran out of memory for pickle, so I had to use csv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not going to get the list back without a bit of work

Use [**`literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to convert the lists

```
import ast

conv = dict(col_1=ast.literal_eval)
pd.read_csv(r'C:\test.csv', index_col=0, converters=conv).loc[0, 'col_1']

['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Awesome! ast module seems very useful. But it is one of the last one described in python docs, which is a pity.